# Jest Expect multiple lines

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am writing tests for my js compiler and when I input a String, multiple lines are retrieved. 
What is retrieved is what I want to retrieve, but my test fails because I don't know how to write what is expected for jest.

This is how I call the test:

```
testRequireImport(
    'import { b, a } from \'@sugar/merge/*\';',
    '!EXPECTED',
    babelOptions
);
```

This is the reaction in the console:

```
    expect(received).toBe(expected)

Expected value to be (using ===):
  "import '../../top/merge/FileInTop.js';,import '../../mid/merge/FileInMid.js';,import '../../mid/merge/Second.js';,import './FileInBot.js';"
Received:
  "import '../../top/merge/FileInTop.js';
import '../../mid/merge/FileInMid.js';
import '../../mid/merge/Second.js';
import './FileInBot.js';"

Difference:

- Expected
+ Received


-import '../../top/merge/FileInTop.js';,import '../../mid/merge/FileInMid.js';,import '../../mid/merge/Second.js';,import './FileInBot.js';
+import '../../top/merge/FileInTop.js';
+import '../../mid/merge/FileInMid.js';
+import '../../mid/merge/Second.js';
+import './FileInBot.js';
```

Can anyone help me with writing what is expected?

Comment: You haven't said what you actually want to happen

Comment: @Aron I want my test to succeed. What I receive is correct, but I want to know how to write the `expected` to be equal to the received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expected has commas where new lines should be, and your received has new lines instead of commas.

So make your expected match with line breaks

`expect(received).toBe(expected.replace(',', '\n'));`

Comment: Thanks! The code you sent didn't work, because `replace` just replaces the first comma, but I used `split` and `join` to make it happen